# How can I get gmake to give me a list of all included makefiles?

Tags: make, gnu-make

I've inherited a major mess of a makefile network that was itself inherited from another project, with makefiles included all over the place. I'm trying to make a simple change without gutting the whole thing (tempting though that is, I just don't have the time right now).

Is there any way to coax a full makefile out of gmake, *i.e.*, with all the included files already included? I know how to get the database dumped, but that's just about as hard to follow with all the extraneous junk that gets loaded in.

Comment: I wonder whether this makes sense in general, since makefiles can be generated dynamically (from the contents) then included.

Comment: Good point, but they don't have to be generated dynamically (such as the "major mess of a makefile network" mentioned above), plus it can still come in handy to find where an explicit target might be hiding.

Answer (score 1):

[Remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) has some very interesting debug output.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an equivalent of `cc -E` for `make`. I'm not aware of such an equivalent. Using external tools will help in many, but not all cases, due to *secondary expansion*.

But maybe this might get you one step closer. At the end of the initial Makefile, add this rule:

```
.PHONY: printMakefiles
printMakefiles:
        echo $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
```

You can now find out which Makefiles were included by running

```
make printMakefiles
```

Please note that this is not 100% reliable, as there could be conditional include.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that works recursively, but what about something like:

```
strace -e trace=open make | grep -i makefile
```

Comment: You should add `-f` to strace for following childs on fork ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `make` doesn't provide any easy way to do that, but perhaps it will be sufficient for you to grep all the `include` directives from all makefiles like this:

```
find . -iname 'Makefile' -print0 | xargs -0 grep '^include'
```

Comment: Nice try, but it doesn't give me the full picture, as it doesn't show me what the first target in the mess is. It also doesn't take into account nested includes, especially when they named **no** include file 'Makefile' or any standard equivalent, and they threw them all over the directory tree.

Comment: Then I don't know an easy way to do that. It seems you are a programmer, so perhaps a suitable way for you is to modify the source code of the `make` and add a message which is printed when an `include` directive is processed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the main `Makefile` that you are invoking.   Add this line at the end (or at least after the last `include` which occurs in the file:

```
$(info MAKEFILE_LIST == $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

Now, when you run `make` on that `Makefile`, it will dump a list of the included files, prior to dispatching the rules.